# Comparing records of two tables and discarding matches

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to implement an idea where I have two sql tables in a database.

Table `Info` which has a field `Nationality` and the other Table `Exclusion` which has a field `Keyword`.

```
`Info.Nationality`               `Exclusion.Keyword`

    |British|                     |France|  
    |resteraunt de France|        |Spanish|
    |German|
    |Flag Italian|
    |Spanish rice|
    |Italian pasta
    |Irish beef|
```

In my web application I am creating a `GridView4` and through a `DataTable` and `SqlDataAdapter` I am populating that `GridView4` with the SQL command:

`SELECT DISTINCT Info.Nationality WHERE Exclusion.Keyword NOT LIKE '%Spanish%'`

That SQL statement retrieves all the distinct records in `Info.Nationality` which do not contain the word spanish.

What I am currently doing is that in the web app which is in vb.net I am adding two different `GridViews`, each have the data of each table which means that `GridView2` has `DISTINCT Info.Nationality` and `GridView3` has `Exclusion.Keyword` and then adding another  `GridView4` to display the results of the above `SQL command`.

The idea is to retrieve all the distinct records from `Info.Nationlity` which are not suppressed by the keyword constraints in `Exclusion.keyword`. So from the above mentioned Sql command the `GridView4` will retrieve all the records which do not have the word "Spanish".

I am doing all of this in a nested `for` loop where in the first loop it takes each record (one by one) from `Info.Nationality` e.g.`for each row As DataRow in Me.GridView2.Rows()` and compare it with the second for loop which goes till the end of the `Exclusion.Keyword` which would be like `For i=0 To Gridview3 - 1`.

The problem is that in that sql statement I have to explicitly specify the word to compare. I tried adding the records of `Exclusion.Keyword` in a `String` and then replacing the `Spanish` Keyword In between the `NOT LIKE` with the name of the `String` which is `Keywords` and then assigning the name a parameter with `cmd.parameter.addwithvalue(@String, Keywords)`. However this is not working, it is only comparing with the last record in the string and ignoring the first.

The idea behind all of this is to display all the records of `Info.Nationality` in `GridView4` which do not contain the keywords in `Exclusion.Keyword`.

Is there an easier or more effecient way to do this? I was thinking of an `Inner Join with a Like command` but that is not my problem. My problem is that how can I compare each record one by one of `Info.Nationlity` with all the records in `Exclusion.keyword` and then retrieving the ones that do not match and discarding the ones that match.

Then in `Gridview4` how can I edit the records without reflecting those changes or affecting in `Info.Nationality` but rather only `Inserting to Exclusion.Keyword` the changes.

**SOLVED** by adding `ToString()` after `Text`
In my asp.net web app, I tried this, but didn't work: (**SOLVED**)

```
 `SELECT DISTINCT Nationality 
FROM Info Where NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Exclusion WHERE Info.Nationality LIKE '%' + @GridView +'%')`

`cmd.parameters.AddwithValue("@GridView", GridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text.ToString())`
```

`GridView3` Here has the `Exclusion.Keywords` data.

Would really appreciate your suggestions and thoughts around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do this one-by-one, or "Row by agonizing row" as some DBAs are fond of describing this type of approach. There are lots of ways to write a query to only return the records from Info.nationality that do not match the exclusion keywords as a single expression.

My preference is to use the `EXISTS` clause and a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Nationality 
FROM Info I
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Exclusion WHERE I.Nationality LIKE '%' + Keyword + '%')
```

You can also express this as a `left join`.

```
SELECT I.Nationality 
FROM Info I
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Exclusion E 
        ON I.Nationality LIKE '%' + E.Keyword + '%'
WHERE E.Keyword IS NULL
```

The `left join` will return all the rows from info and insert nulls in the columns for Exclusion except where the join criteria matches. By filtering for only where those values are null, you can avoid the matches.

Comment: rather than specifying explicitly the keyword in `'%' + Keyword + '%')`, that keyword should be the ones in the `Exclusion.Keywords`. I don't know how to write, but logically it should say something like `...Where NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Exclusion WHERE I.Nationality LIKE '%' the keywords in Exclusion.Keywords '%')`. Is that possible?

Comment: No keyword is being explicitly referred to. Where you see "keyword" in the query, it's actually referencing the column in the table.

Comment: I'm glad you got something working but from your posted solution you apparently misunderstood the query I provided. In your code the NOT EXISTS is redundant since you're really just doing a where. Assuming you provided accurate table and column names in your question, the top query will retrieve all nationalities that don't contain the exclude keywords as it's written. No parameters are necessary.